# Debye length for a debye shield

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, plasma-physics, debye-length

I understand debye length and even the concept of debye shielding, but quantitatively I'm a little confused. If the debye shield has a potential of $$\Phi=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r}\exp\left({\frac{-r}{\lambda_{D}}}\right)$$ and I insert a positive ion (proton) into a plasma, will the debye length around this ion be the same as the debye length of the plasma? What exactly is $r$ in this equation?

Comment: $r$ is just the radial distance from the center of an arbitrary Debye sphere.

Comment: @honeste_vivere is that not just the debye length?

Comment: @NotSoN - $r$ need not be the Debye length, but a Debye sphere has a radius of one $\lambda_{D}$.

Comment: You might want to have a look into this answer, it should contain everything you need: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/502255